# When to use generator TensorFlow in time series

Tags: tensorflow, generator, lstm

I'm building a LSTM ANN and I'm not sure of using generator in my case. The net should have several hyperparameters it should iterate, e.g. epochs, activation functions..., however, if the generator is used in this case, each iteration is trained on different set, right? So more correct is using list or array instead? Thank you

```
for epoch in EPOCHS do:
for activation in ACTIVATION do:
trainLSTM(epoch, activation)
save best model
```

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended using `Generator` for `Time Series Data` which has been explained in detail in the [Tutorial of Tensorflow Time Series Analysis](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series). Code for such a `Generator` is shown below:

```
class WindowGenerator():
  def __init__(self, input_width, label_width, shift,
               train_df=train_df, val_df=val_df, test_df=test_df,
               label_columns=None):
    # Store the raw data.
    self.train_df = train_df
    self.val_df = val_df
    self.test_df = test_df

    # Work out the label column indices.
    self.label_columns = label_columns
    if label_columns is not None:
      self.label_columns_indices = {name: i for i, name in
                                    enumerate(label_columns)}
    self.column_indices = {name: i for i, name in
                           enumerate(train_df.columns)}

    # Work out the window parameters.
    self.input_width = input_width
    self.label_width = label_width
    self.shift = shift

    self.total_window_size = input_width + shift

    self.input_slice = slice(0, input_width)
    self.input_indices = np.arange(self.total_window_size)[self.input_slice]

    self.label_start = self.total_window_size - self.label_width
    self.labels_slice = slice(self.label_start, None)
    self.label_indices = np.arange(self.total_window_size)[self.labels_slice]

  def __repr__(self):
    return '\n'.join([
        f'Total window size: {self.total_window_size}',
        f'Input indices: {self.input_indices}',
        f'Label indices: {self.label_indices}',
        f'Label column name(s): {self.label_columns}'])
```

For example, if your `Data` is from the years, 1960 (Jan 1st) to 2016 (Dec 31st) and that you want to `predict` the weather of the entire February Month for the year 2017, by considering a Data Window of past 2 Years, the values of the arguments of the above class are shown below:

```
input_width: 2 Years => 365 * 2 = 730
label_width: Entire Feb Month => 28
shift: We are not predicting from Jan 1st 2017 but are shifting by entire Month of Jan => 30
train_df, test_df, val_df => Self Explanatory
label_columns : Name of the Target Column
```